# Is there any way to can install airflow on kubernetes on premise

Tags: airflow-scheduler, airflow

I am new to airflow and need assistance on how to install airflow on k8s .
Needs are:

1 . How to Build docker image of airflow only for webserver and scheduler

2 . How to Build separate docker image for MySQL

3 . How to create airflow.cfg with kunernetes executor?

4 . Any sample would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean Apache Airflow - you can just use existed helm chart, that described here https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/kubernetes.html

Unfortunately from your description it is not clear what kind of problem you want to solve.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31697642)